# PostgreSQL Array vs Columns

Tags: arrays, database, postgresql, database-design

I am looking to store a very large amount of small values in a Postgres db.  Ultimately, there will initially be c. 10,000 users answering around 400 questions in the next year.  I need to track the individual statuses of the users answers to these questions.

I could do this with a simple table that has a `user_id` and `question_id` and two `timestamp`s called `last_attempted` and `correct`.  However, I'm concerned that this table will grow and grow and grow into the millions of rows.

My question is, is PostgreSQL efficient enough to deal with tables of this structure with millions of rows or would it be better to look into using Postgres Arrays for each user, or otherwise use Redis or Memcached for this specific purpose?

Comment: We handle about 400 million records per month, for 3 years. No problem at all. But it's all about how you use this data, your SQL and the indexes. And of course the hardware, you do need some fast storage when it doesn't fit into RAM anymore.

Comment: Well I'd index the foreign keys ... it's quite a simple structure to migrate so I think I'll go with this model for now, especially given the size that you manage ok!